# R: row number of the minimum value in each column

Tags: r, matrix, minimum

I've got a matrix and now I search for the minimum value of EACH column. I've got de next code:

```
error.mars1[which(error.mars1==0)] = NA
minValue = min(error.mars1[,2],na.rm=T)
```

I've used NA because I want a nonzero minimum value. So this was to get the mean of column 2. But now I want the row number for which this is the minimum value. Can someone help me?

Comment: You asked a variant the same question an hour ago and it was answered there ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: Get the row and column name of the minimum element of a matrix but with minimum != 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007875/r-get-the-row-and-column-name-of-the-minimum-element-of-a-matrix-but-with-minim)

Comment: Right, but then I've used min(which(error.mars1[,2] == minValue)

Comment: @Silke You used it as an example, but I think your question was fairly clear that you needed values for all columns not just the second one :) Thanks for changing your mind. I will delete my above comment as no longer relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what you are asking about is given by:

```
apply(error.mars1, 2, function(x) which(x == min(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Alternatively:

```
apply(error.mars1, 2, which.min)
```

Comment: The second element must be 2 for columns, and your second proposal gives the same result as the first (I tested). I edited your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I just do not have R where I am now to test :) The second is just a short form for the first.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`which(error.mars1[,2] == minValue)`