# SQL finding minimum that is non-zero

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have issues finding the minimum values that are non-zero.

For example, I have a table that show the amount of money earned by each person, and some of them don't earn anything. I would like to exclude those that don't earn anything and find the names of people who earn the least (that is non-zero).

I tried this:

```
SELECT name, earnings
FROM paylist
WHERE earnings = (SELECT min(earnings)
            FROM paylist) AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                         FROM paylist
                                         WHERE earning <> 0)
```

But I realised that the min(earnings) will just become 0 and return no values in the output.
How should I go about writing the query?

Also, I am told there could be two ways to write this: 
1. with aggregate functions (e.g. COUNT, SUM, MAX, MIN)
2. without using any aggregate functions
What's the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099720/mysql-find-min-but-not-zero

Comment: "find **the** person" - If it's only one person then you can use ORDER BY and LIMIT 1.

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question, the output should list all the names of people who earned the least.

Answer (score 3):

Use the condition in the sub query to omit the rows with zero earnings and find minimum earning and use it outside.

```
select name,
    earnings
from paylist
where earnings = (
        select min(earnings)
        from paylist
        where earnings <> 0
        )
```

Or use `nullif` which can use the fact that min return minimum non-null value:

```
select name,
    earnings
from paylist
where earnings = (
        select min(nullif(earnings,0))
        from paylist
        )
```

The difference is that the first one can use index if any. The above two will return all the rows with minimum non-zero earnings

If you just want one row with least non-zero earnings, you can use `limit` (no aggregation needed):

```
select *
from paylist
where earnings <> 0
order by earnings
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a Table **T00188SK** which has a total of 6 Columns (id, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4) where id is the AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY Column. If you want to find the lowest value from (C0, C1, C2, C3, C4) except Zero

MySQL has a neat way to do this. Simply go:

**SELECT LEAST(MIN(NULLIF(C0, 0)), MIN(NULLIF(C1, 0)), MIN(NULLIF(C2, 0)), MIN(NULLIF(C3, 0)), MIN(NULLIF(C4, 0))) AS finalmin FROM `T00188SK`**

#SQL #MySQL #Database